# Protecting a html page from access (except for redirected users)

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I have a html page with information I would only like my signup form redirect traffic to see. When users sign up they will get redirected there, but I dont want someone who finds out about that page accessing it.

For example

www.buyshoes123.com has a sign up form, and when users sign up, they'll automatically be redirected to;

www.buyshoes123.com/discount.html

Is there a way to hide this discount.html page from anyone else but the redirected users? For example, if a user decides to copy-paste this address and give it to his colleague, how can I prevent it from displaying?

Comment: you could add a cookie/session pair to the sign up form, then if the cookie doesn't exist, redirect back to your homepage.

Comment: Can you point me to some tutorial or some keywords I could look up on that subject, since Im not very (obviously :) ) cookie-savvy

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the cookie solution mentioned in a comment is good enough here. What you are dealing with here in general is *identity management*. Registration should result in an identity creation for the registering user and start a managed (logged in) *session*. Then, on your protected page, you must check for identity and session. You will *have to* utilise some server side scripting to achieve this.

Comment: great idea, completely slipped my mind that an actual user account is going to be created.